# JavaScript сума значений массива по пользователю за текущую дату

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

В js я абсолютный новичек. Нужно разобраться с задачей. Есть массив данных:

```
{
    "id": 30,
    "agent_id": 180,
    "first_name": "Daniel",
    "last_name": "Brian",
    "country": null,
    "amount": 3952.83,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "date": "2021-02-09",
    "brand": "TradersPros",
    "role": "Retention - morning killers Agents",
    "img": "",
    "is_ftd": true
},
{
    "id": 31,
    "agent_id": 86,
    "first_name": "Ben",
    "last_name": "Russo",
    "country": null,
    "amount": 894.96,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "date": "2021-02-09",
    "brand": "TradersPros",
    "role": "Retention - Mosad Agents",
    "img": "",
    "is_ftd": true
},
{
    "id": 32,
    "agent_id": 35,
    "first_name": "Max",
    "last_name": "Schmidt",
    "country": null,
    "amount": 214.0,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "date": "2021-02-09",
    "brand": "TradersPros",
    "role": "FTD - Minions Agents",
    "img": "",
    "is_ftd": true
},
{
    "id": 33,
    "agent_id": 178,
    "first_name": "nate",
    "last_name": "jansen",
    "country": null,
    "amount": 4959.54,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "date": "2021-02-09",
    "brand": "TradersPros",
    "role": "Retention - morning killers Agents",
    "img": "",
    "is_ftd": true
}
```

Первоначальная задача просуммировать по польователям значения ячейки amount
Это я делаю с помощью следующего кода:

```
var counttop = result.reduce((res, el) => {
            var el1 = res.find(i => i.agent_id == el.agent_id);
            if (!el1) {
              el1 = { 
                id: el.id,
                agent_id: el.agent_id,
                first_name: el.first_name,
                last_name: el.last_name,
                date: el.date,
                country: el.country,
                amount: 0,
                currency: el.currency,
                img: el.img,
                role: el.role,
                is_ftd: el.is_ftd
              };
              res.push(el1);
            }
            el1.amount += el.amount;
            return res;
          }, []);
```

Но теперь нужно сделать тоже саммое, просуммировать amount по пользователям но только ща текущий день.
Помогите модифицировать мой код для решения этой задачи. Спасибо

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста — у вас в массиве есть элементы с одинаковым agent_id? А остальные поля у них тоже одинаковые? Например, поле id — оно разное? Если разное, то вы копируете в конечные данные значение первого встретившегося элемента?

Answer (score 0):

Добавляешь условие в find

```
var el1 = res.find(i => (i.agent_id == el.agent_id {AND УсловиеПоДате}));
```

Comment: такой метод не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Если я неправильно понял условия, поправьте, пожалуйста.

Ваш текущий код можно немного упростить. Ниже будет пример с вашим упрощённым вариантом и там же второй вариант с добавленной фильтрацией по дате:

```js
const result = [
  {
      "id": 30,
      "agent_id": 180,
      "first_name": "Daniel",
      "last_name": "Brian",
      "country": null,
      "amount": 3952.83,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-18",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Retention - morning killers Agents",
      "img": "",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
  {
      "id": 31,
      "agent_id": 86,
      "first_name": "Ben",
      "last_name": "Russo",
      "country": null,
      "amount": 894.96,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-18",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Retention - Mosad Agents",
      "img": "",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
  {
      "id": 32,
      "agent_id": 35,
      "first_name": "Max",
      "last_name": "Schmidt",
      "country": null,
      "amount": 214.0,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-19",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "FTD - Minions Agents",
      "img": "",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
  {
      "id": 33,
      "agent_id": 178,
      "first_name": "nate",
      "last_name": "jansen",
      "country": null,
      "amount": 4959.54,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-19",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Retention - morning killers Agents",
      "img": "",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
];

const counttop = result.reduce((res, el) => {
  let el1 = res.find(({ agent_id }) => agent_id === el.agent_id);
  if (!el1) res.push(el1 = {...el, amount: 0});
  el1.amount += el.amount;
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(counttop);

const today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

const counttopToday = result.reduce((res, el) => {
  if (el.date !== today) return res;

  let el1 = res.find(({ agent_id }) => agent_id === el.agent_id);
  if (!el1) res.push(el1 = {...el, amount: 0});
  el1.amount += el.amount;
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(counttopToday);
```

А ещё код можно немного ускорить: вместо того, чтобы каждый раз перебирать строящийся массив результатов в поисках нужного элемента, можно строить объект с ключами agent_id и использовать значение по ключу, а потом просто вернуть значения объекта как массив. Если не запутаетесь, можно использовать вот такой вариант:

```js
const result = [
  {
      "id": 30,
      "agent_id": 180,
      "first_name": "Daniel",
      "last_name": "Brian",
      "country": null,
      "amount": 3952.83,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-18",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Retention - morning killers Agents",
      "img": "",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
  {
      "id": 31,
      "agent_id": 86,
      "first_name": "Ben",
      "last_name": "Russo",
      "country": null,
      "amount": 894.96,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-18",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Retention - Mosad Agents",
      "img": "",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
  {
      "id": 32,
      "agent_id": 35,
      "first_name": "Max",
      "last_name": "Schmidt",
      "country": null,
      "amount": 214.0,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-19",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "FTD - Minions Agents",
      "img": "",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
  {
      "id": 33,
      "agent_id": 178,
      "first_name": "nate",
      "last_name": "jansen",
      "country": null,
      "amount": 4959.54,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "date": "2021-02-19",
      "brand": "TradersPros",
      "role": "Retention - morning killers Agents",
      "img": "",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
];

const counttop = Object.values(result.reduce((res, el) => {
  res[el.agent_id] ??= {...el, amount: 0};
  res[el.agent_id].amount += el.amount;
  return res;
}, {}));

console.log(counttop);

const today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

const counttopToday = Object.values(result.reduce((res, el) => {
  if (el.date !== today) return res;

  res[el.agent_id] ??= {...el, amount: 0};
  res[el.agent_id].amount += el.amount;
  return res;
}, {}));

console.log(counttopToday);
```